# pg_ctl status responds with "available" during failed startup

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am using `pg_ctl -D $PGDATA status` to monitor whether my postgres standby database is up and running. Sometimes the database fails to start due to a missing WAL file, but its status is reported as "available".

Is there a simple way to see if postgres is available using the `pg_ctl status` option, or do I need to write a script to query the postgres database and monitor the output from script?

Comment: Details please - exact PostgreSQL version, PostgreSQL log file output, etc.

Comment: sorry, postgres 9.2 running on redhat 6. It's not really an issue which requires the log file. Startup is hanging due to a missing WAL file (which is correct behaviour), but the pg_ctl .. status shows it as available. So is there a magic flag to use with pg_ctl (or some other simple method) of checking postgres is available?

Comment: Is it in `hot_standby` mode? If so, it *is* available, if it's replayed enough that it's accepting connections and responding to queries.

Comment: it is in hot_standby, but you can't connect to it as it has been unable to bring itself up to date due to lost WAL file (i'm testing what happens in the event of the standby being required after a failure.

so trying to access psql give "psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up". But status shows as "available"

Comment: Uh, that doesn't seem right at all then...

Comment: yeah it's a bit annoying as i had a cronjob to email me the result of the ...status command, so i thought everything was ok, but in reality it wasn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pg_ctl status` command tests that the `postmaster` process (corresponding to `$PGDATA`) does exist from the point of view of the operating system. In the positive case, it reports that it's **running** (note that the word `available` is not used).

Essentially that's implemented by reading `postmaster.pid` and checking the result of `kill(that_pid, 0)`.

It does not mean that this PostgreSQL instance does accept connections or is able to execute queries. To that purpose, better use `psql` or a script like Nagios [check_postgres](https://github.com/bucardo/check_postgres) plugin.

Comment: It strikes me that we should add `pg_ctl status -w` or similar, i.e. something that, like `-w` does for start/stop, makes an actual `libpq` connection.